# purchase physical goods from ecommerce app in iphone

Tags: iphone, paypal, in-app-purchase

I have read that in-app purchases can only be used for digital goods. But in the app I am developing, users can purchase 'physical' goods, like they do on websites. Because of this I need to use PayPal for payments. Which brings me to my problem - I have read that apps (tend to be) rejected because of PayPal integration.

Assuming this is true, what (legal) ways exist for me to allow for purchase of goods just as is done on websites like Amazon? Goods like cds, music albums etc?

Answer (score 0):

Everything I'm seeing says it will be rejected, but that doesn't mean it's "illegal".  It just means it's against the Apple terms to get listed in their store.

You could build any kind of app you want and distribute it yourself.  You just wouldn't be able to get it listed in the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Your app won't be rejected for physical good or PayPal integration per se, eBay does just fine. But if you're selling *anything*, and you want to be in the App Store, Apple wants their 30%. If you work within their systems for getting their cut, you'll be fine. If not, you'll need to do your selling from a web page. Keep in mind, that Apple aren't fools, and they *really* want their 30%. A "buy" button in your app that simply opens the purchase process in Safari won't get you past the gatekeepers.

Comment: I'm having web app for music store from that available song you can put it in to your cart.So for that can i use paypal?

Comment: As long as there's no clickable link from your native App Store application to the web site.